# Write directly to Amazon S3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I am reading Amazon S3 documentation, but I am bit lost...

Actually, user upload a file to Amazon S3, then, I copy it to EC2, proccess it, back to S3 and user can download it.

When I proccess the file, I need to create a html file, and I need to create in Amazon S3, but I don't know how can I create this file directly on S3. Right now, I create a file on EC2 and then I move it to S3.

To create this html y use:

```
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(pathFile);
            tw.WriteLine(page);
            tw.Close();
```

Where *page* is a string with html code, and pathFile is: `string outputWap = Server.MapPath("~/xxx.html");`

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2.

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the AWS SDK for .Net you could try using [`PutObjectRequest`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_PutObjectRequest.htm) with the `InputStream` set instead of `FilePath` although I haven't tried this myself.

Otherwise I don't really see what's wrong with the way you are currently doing it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Geoff, I'm going to try it, and I will leave a feedback.
I'm glad to know that is'n wrong this way.

PD: I forgot, yes, I'm using AWS SDK for .NET :)

Comment: Finally I write html file on EC2 and copy it to S3. The same way than other files.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can not create (not to be confused with uploading which of course is entirely feasible) a file in s3 (at least with the .net SDK) at this time. If you have no control over the local file system (space limitations, permissions, or otherwise) you can create a file in memory and then upload that stream to s3 as if it were a file stored locally on disk. Code for c# would be as follows:

```
public static bool CreateFile()
    {
        // Create file in memory
        UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();

        // Create the data to write to the stream.
        byte[] memstring = uniEncoding.GetBytes("you're file content here");
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(100))
        {
            memStream.Write(memstring, 0, memstring.Length);

            // upload to s3
            try
            {
                AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
                using (Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility tranUtility =
                              new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(s3))
                {
                    tranUtility.Upload(memStream, bucketname, keyname);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the following articles, I think they are pertinent:

http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html
http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Regards, Ashok

Answer (score 0):

I'am doing this:

```
public bool Upload(string filePath, Stream inputStream, double contentLength, string contentType)
{
  try
  {
      var request = new PutObjectRequest();
      string _bucketName = "";

      request.BucketName = _bucketName;
      request.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
      request.InputStream = inputStream;
      request.Key = filePath;
      request.Headers.ContentType = contentType;

      PutObjectResponse response = _amazonS3Client.PutObject(request);

      return true;

  }catch(Exception ex)
  {
      return false;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** The Stream parameter i can pass by using:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = this.Request.Files[0];
file.Stream;
```